# why UITableViewAutomaticDimension not working for sectionFooterHeight?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi there is plenty of question answering the dynamic height for `UITableViewCell` of `UITableView`. However I find it weird when I did it for `sectionFooterHeight`.

Code as:

```
 tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 25

 tableView.sectionFooterHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 50
```

And have set  constraints in `xib` for footer view

Although it works for `headerview` but not for footer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement the `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: If this doesn't work either, you have some constraints set wrong

Comment: This is not true

Answer (score 0):

Once you've set your estimatedSectionFooterHeight to a number and set sectionFooterHeight equal to UITableViewAutomaticDimension, you can implement `tableView:heightForFooterInSection:` and return tableView.sectionFooterHeight

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.